# What is value of OpenCart customer_id on oc_oder for guest account

Tags: opencart

We are using OpenCart. In case of guest checkout, what would be the value of customer_id on oc_order? I would assume that it would be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap you are right.

You can find it specified in **catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php**

```
            elseif (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) {
            $data['customer_id'] = 0;
```